# Rancher Desktop - nerdctl watch command does not work

Tags: docker, rancher-desktop, nerdctl

So I have switched from Docker to Rancher Desktop. License reason!

I have added an alias in my terminal profile to docker `alias docker="nerdctl"`

Running `docker ps`works fine and I get the output. As soon as I run `watch docker ps` I get the error that the docker daemon is not running:

Error:

```bash
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Anyone who could give me a hint how to solve that?